# Clang Tidy Integration with msbuild command line

Tags: c++, msbuild, clang, clang-tidy

I have worked on previous projects using CMake and clang tidy and was able to generate the compilation database. However, I am working on project using [C++ builder](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder) and would like to run clang tidy on the codebase. There doesn't seem to be much online regarding clang-tidy integration on a project not using CMake. Does anyone know what is specifically required to get this to work.Under the hood we are using msbuild to build the project

Comment: So what build process are you using?

Comment: @GeorgP `msbuild`